# Visual Basic - changing from Integer to string query

Tags: sql, vb.net, types

Please bear with me, i'm a relative beginner and have done my best to resolve this issue before posting here.

I wrote a VB application a few years ago which, bar a few mods, has stayed in good function. I've now been asked about the practicality of changing our case referencing format from seven integers (i.e. 1232017) to an alpha-numeric format such as 'AB-12345-17' - and this is causing me some headaches.

I've tried defining that data as a string instead, but know it's not that simple.

FYI - The connection function is working and 'Textbox1' is where the user input the Case Ref - for which I then query the SQL db for the related Case Name:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1

 Dim SQLConn As SqlClient.SqlConnection
 Dim NAME As String
 Dim REF As String

Public Sub get_Name()

    'create a connection
    connection()

    Using cmdobj As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select name from dbo.Cases where Reference = " & TextBox1.Text, SQLConn)
        Using readerobj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdobj.ExecuteReader
            While readerobj.Read
                NAME = readerobj("case_name").ToString
            End While
        End Using
    End Using

    'close the connection
    SQLConn.Close()
```

Having created a test case with the new naming convention, i receive an error for the line;

```
Using readerobj As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdobj.ExecuteReader
```

... to say "an unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLClient.SQLException' occurred in System.Data.dll - Additional information: Invalid column name 'AB'"

This is obviously an issue about defining the data in the textbox properly to allow it to be used as part of the query - does it requiring conversion in some way?

Thanks in advance

Richard

Comment: try enclosing the string in an extra pair of quotes. Something like "select name from dbo.cases where reference= ' "& Textbox1.text & " ' "

Comment: @Sivaprasath V - Oh, how i hoped it wasn't so simple - i feel really stupid now!! Thanks, that worked.

Comment: As a side note, use  sql command parameters. Besides preventing problems as one above you'll get protection against sql injection.

Comment: What will happen if the user enters `''; drop table dbo.Cases` into your text box?

Comment: I bet it will drop the table :) or how able ''; drop table dbo.Cases; CREATE LOGIN [Domain\User] FROM WINDOWS; CREATE LOGIN [LoginName] WITH PASSWORD = 'SomePassword';

Comment: @ Chris Dunaway - in a nutshell - all hell will break loose!! Fortunately, there's probably only two people in our office who know such a thing. I've now figured a way of reverting back to an integer for that box, so there's less chance again.

Comment: I only asked to make you aware that you have a gaping hole in the security of your app.  Learn how to use parameterized queries.  They're just as easy as what you are doing now and they will close that security hole.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway - thanks for the advice - i am working on making the textbox only receive numbers and i also need to pad it out to five digits with '0's. Fortunately this little program is only used by 9 other in my office, and they're unlikely to try such as thing as they'd all be out of a job!!

Comment: And you're sure they wouldn't do it out of vindictiveness if they left or were fired?  Why not write the code the right way the first time around rather than having to change it later just in case?